Can I use "historically" to mean "for a long time" in "Historically, the Japanese were almost vegetarian"?


Historically, the Japanese were almost vegetarian.

The Japanese were almost vegetarian for a long time.



Is it possible to use (1) to mean (2)?
I do not know whether "historically" can mean "for a long time" in some past tense sentences. I have consulted the American Heritage Dictionary, Collins English Dictionary, and some learners' dictionaries, but none even defines "historically".
I would like to see the OED's definition of "historically". (I do not own the OED because it is prohibitively expensive and might be too difficult for Japanese learners of English to use.)

Historically does not mean 'for a long time'.

Also, I might say 'largely' or 'mostly' rather than 'almost'. Saying 'almost vegetarian' implies that they were not vegetarian.

@WeatherVane My wife and I are vegetarian, and it grinds our gears when people say they are 'nearly' so. Often they think 'white' meat (chicken) and fish don't really count, and you'd be amazed how many alleged 'vegetarians' don't mind a meat burger or hot dog when they've had a drink or two (and they've made a fuss beforehand!).

@MichaelHarvey a vegetarian colleague will eat fish at a business lunch if there is no veggie menu, rather than go hungry, and people who know him have been quite rude, calling him a hypocrite. He's not a secret meatie, though.

I would avoid the term vegetarian as people have different interpretations on what it entails. You could say something like: For over XXX years, the typical Japanese diet was, with few exceptions, plant-based.

@WeatherVane - I wouldn't say your colleague was a hypocrite; that's a bit strong. If I were him I'd call myself 'pescatarian'. I once asked my Jewish brother-in-law if there is such a thing as being 'almost kosher' and he laughed and said 'that's just about every Jew that I know'.

"I have consulted the American Heritage Dictionary, Collins English Dictionary, and some learners' dictionaries, but none even defines 'historically'. I would like to see the OED's definition of 'historically'." I'd recommend Merriam-Webster as an "in-between." For a learner, the dilemma is that dictionaries like MW or OED can be hard to use, as they might just explain one word you don't know using another that you don't know, or they might not give a lot of usage examples; but meanwhile "learner's dictionaries," while solving these problems, might sometimes give the wrong impression or...

... be less thorough to avoid overwhelming you. So I'd suggest starting with a learner's dictionary, but any time you find it confusing or inadequate, moving up to MW. (And it's still more "ordinary-person-friendly" than the OED.)

@MichaelHarvey if I say I walk to work, that doesn't mean I'm not allowed to drive sometimes, or am a fraud. He prefers not to create an awkward scene at a business lunch, although he's a vegetarian the rest of the time.

@WeatherVane - I don't know about 'causing an awkward scene' (whatever that means) at a business lunch, but I would definitely decline any meat or fish dish. By the way, I have done exactly this, and nobody minded. If I had previously indicated that I required a vegetarian option, I would have grounds for complaint, surely? Supinely eating fish would make me despise myself for a cowardly weakling and destroy my relationship with my employers and any clients present.

There's also: quasi-vegatarian or semi-vegetarian [How about eating insects?], Also, pescatarian (fish).

It's probably best to ask a new question (if one doesn't already exist) for what term you should use instead of "almost vegetarian". In the comments here is not the place to have that discussion.

@WeatherVane: Not explicitly, but "historically" does imply that you're looking back some reasonable length of time, not just 5 minutes. If OP's "a long time" (which is subjective in their own mind) sufficiently fits what most people would consider a reasonable minimum time frame for "historically" to start making sense, this does work. Not purely because of "historically", but "historically" + "have been" suggests a longstanding state.

To me, "almost vegetarian" implies 100% of Japanese people ate very little meat, poultry or fish. "Mostly vegetarians" implies, say, 95% of Japanese people ate no meat, poulty, or fish and the remainder did.

Any statement about the past implies a longstanding state. If I say "The Romans fought with swords and spears" this suggests it's something they did often, not just once. "The Japanese were almost vegetarian" is a categorical statement, which means they didn't eat much meat for a long time in the past. Adding "historically" weakens it: it emphasises that it was true at some time in the past, but not necessarily today.

Nor do I have a subscription to the OED. But here is the Merriam-Webster definition for historically:

1: In accordance with or with respect to history
a historically accurate account
2: In the past
historically, stagnant cities seldom have recovered

Your example uses historically in the second sense: you are saying something about Japanese society in the past.
Note that although historically places the setting in the past, it does not say anything about length of time. The history of computers will be shorter than the history of farming.
Finally, and as noted in the comments, you probably don't want to say almost vegetarian. Almost in this case should qualify Japanese, not vegetarian. You're talking about many Japanese people being vegetarian (rather than Japanese being vegetarians Monday to Friday but not weekends). So in summary you want to say:

Historically, most (or many) Japanese people were vegetarians.


Thank you, Peter Kirkpatrick. Does the following sentence work for you? Historically, almost all Japanese were near-vegetarian for about 1,200 years.

Grammatically the sentence is fine. As regards near-vegetarian, I would understand that you are saying, They eat a little meat but mostly vegetables. So if that's what you mean, it's fine.

@PeterKirkpatrick  Almost vegetarian because of some animal produce. Are eggs veg or non-veg? Cambridge dictionary: vegetarian
noun [ C ] -
a person who does not eat meat for health or for religious or moral reasons: -
Some vegetarians avoid eggs and dairy products as well as meat.

@Kaguyahime I find "historically" to be either redundant or vague in that example. 1,200 clearly includes "the past!" If the meaning is "for some period of 1,200 years of the past history, not counting back from today, but rather from some point in history," then it makes you wonder when that point is. Meanwhile, you were right to think initially that "historically" does carry some sense of a significant pattern: This entry says "in the past, especially typically or routinely." It's not necessarily the same as "for a long unbroken period

... of time," but "Historically, the Japanese etc." is perhaps the same as "In the past, the Japanese [were mostly etc.], or [were typically etc.], or [were etc. to some significant degree]."

"You're talking about many Japanese people being vegetarian (rather than Japanese being vegetarians Monday to Friday but not weekends)" - I thought it was talking about Japanese people generally eating very little meat.

"Historically" doesn't quite say nothing about the length of time, it usually implies a routine or duration long enough to be historically documented. One would not use "historically" to describe short-term or one-off events. As you suggest, context is key to guess at what kind of duration is hinted at by "historically" - I'd say talking about the historical trends of nations often indicates a reasonable duration.

@NuclearHoagie: Indeed.  People saying "people historically did X" implies that people routinely did X long enough for it to become a custom that, at the time, was not expected to end in the foreseeable future.  Saying that television programs were historically stored on magnetic tape does not imply that nobody imagined that some better storage medium might come along, but nobody during the 1980s would have viewed the use of videotape as a "stop-gap" measure until optical storage became practical.

@JamesMathai In common usage, "vegetarian" refers to people that eat dairy and eggs, and "vegan" refers to people who don't. The Cambridge dictionary confirms.

@FedericoPoloni Cambridge dictionary: Some vegetarians avoid eggs and dairy products as well as meat.

@JamesMathai That's a sentence given for an example of usage, not part of the definition. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vegetarian

@KarlKnechtel there are plenty of other contexts where a group of people ate very little meat, usually out of necessity, but in this case I suspect OP really did mean that most people ate no meat (reflecting the influence of Buddhism).

The meanings "most Japanese people were vegetarian, but some weren't" and "Japanese people mostly ate vegetarian foods, but ate some meat on rare occasions" are both compatible with the sentence as written.  "Japanese people were all vegetarian, but only during a specific period of time" is not.  The exact definition of vegetarian is another question.

Historically historically referred to history. Which covers everything since humans wrote a written record up until right now. Before that was a period we call prehistory.

"Nor do I have a subscription to the OED." This first sentence seems to refer to one before it. Is something missing here?

The OED reference is in the OP.

I would avoid the term vegetarian as people have different interpretations of what it signifies. Today it is common to talk about  plant-based foods and diets, but it's also important to note that it does not exclude animal produce.

Generally speaking, a plant-based diet consists largely of vegetables, fruit, beans, legumes, grains and nuts, with little or no meat, dairy or fish. People who follow plant-based diets do so for reasons of health, animal welfare concerns, or environmental consciousness.
Source: The New York Times

You could say something similar to:

Between XXX and XXXX, the typical Japanese diet was, with few exceptions, mostly plant-based.

The term historically is imprecise, are we speaking about 400 years ago or 2,000? Likewise, the expression "for a long time" could easily refer to the 20th century. By stating the number of years, and its historical period, we produce a more precise and less ambiguous statement.

Do you have to say both "with a few exceptions" and "mostly"? They mean pretty much the same in this context. Maybe you could also say something like "Up until XXX years ago …"  since I presume the OP is contrasting historic diet with the current, western influenced one. Particularly as there is no indication that still further into the past there was more meat in their diet.

@PeterJennings the Wikipedia link in the answer suggests that vegetarianism was practiced between 710 and 1868, but I am not qualified to know how accurate that information is. I will however, thanks to your observation, modify my answer. As for "with few exceptions" and "mostly" sometimes a little redundancy is acceptable in writing.

Good answer. Avoiding a one-word term and spelling out what the diet actually was is the best approach.  I also can’t help thinking the original use of “Vegetarian” is factually wrong, unless you limit discussion to the poorer part of society. While consumption of animal meat was low in Japan before the Meiji restoration of 1868 brought more Western influences, fish was certainly eaten by the wealthier classes in significant quantities. “Pescatarian” would be the modern term, but it’s always better to say what one means rather than hope the reader knows the precise meaning of a word.

I don't know enough about the history of Japanese cuisine to know whether your statement is factually correct, or how confusing "almost vegetarian" might be.  I will focus instead on the use of "historically."
"Historically," when used to describe a people or practice, implies:

The practice was widespread or important in the community being described, though not necessarily universal
It extended from the beginning of the community, or from before the beginning of its known or recorded history
The practice ended recently (relative to how long it was in effect), although there is flexibility here depending on context
The community in question still exists, they just have changed

Good examples:
"Historically, the Lakota had a semi-nomadic lifestyle based on seasonal farming and buffalo hunting."
This was the lifestyle for about a thousand years, predating the tribe's recorded history, but it is no longer possible since the late 19th century.
"Historically, television viewers watched broadcast programming, but today they mostly watch streaming video."
Even though television has only existed for about 80 years, because this change occurred mostly in the last decade, this works well.  After about 2050, this usage will become increasingly awkward.
Bad examples:
"Historically, the United States elects the President indirectly, through the Electoral College."
This system has been in place for almost 250 years, but it is still in effect, so this is a bad usage.
"Historically, the Vikings were a primarily pastoral and trading culture, but supplemented their wealth with the raids they are famous for."
This is a bad example because there was no time in known history when the Vikings did not work this way, and there are no Vikings any more.  Just because something happened in history, that doesn't mean you should say "historically."
Complex, possibly misleading example:
"Historically, the Jewish religion was based around worship at the Temple in Jerusalem."
The (second) Temple was destroyed in 70 CE, so this is not a relatively recent change, and would confuse readers who do not already know the history.  However, if you were writing about Judaism in the second or late first centuries CE, this would be recent relative to what you are describing, and therefore it would work in that situation.  But if you were writing about Judaism prior to 70 CE, it would again not work, because the practice would still be in effect, from the perspective of your writing.
There is a second usage of "historically":
The other usage of "historically" is to emphasize the factual accuracy of your statement, especially in contrast to what the reader might already believe.
"The popular conception of Vikings is of a culture based on raiding and pillaging, but historically, they mostly engaged in fishing, farming, herding, or trading."
See how similar this example is to the bad example about the Vikings above, but uses "historically" in its other sense.

If you're trying to describe a situation where a national dietary culture underwent some dramatic change, then historically is apt; or you could also use for a long time  though that phrase is rather informal in tone and it also is not very clear about the length of time, and it doesn't explicitly indicate anything about the national culture, which historically does:
It would be a situation that called for the past perfect:

Historically, red meat had not been a major element of the Japanese diet. But during the latter half of the 20th century ...
For a very long time the Japanese diet had included very little red meat. Things changed when highly marbled beef became popular during the second half of the 20th century.


You're saying "on an historical scale", "over history the Japanese were almost vegetarian" or "throughout history". Yes it's valid. People would understand what you meant. That, together with "were", implies this was in the past and might no longer hold true.
It's fairly common use.

The other answers are overthinking it.  Yes, this usage is correct. I don't have a source to back this up, but speaking as a native speaker, this usage of "historically" is perfectly idiomatic and will be understood correctly.
The caveat, of course, is that "historically" is nonspecific.  But so is "for a long time" or "in the past".  Each of these phrases may be used if the specific time period is implied, or is clarified immediately afterwards.  In fact, "historically" might even be preferred due to its conciseness.  So for example, a passage like the following can be used:

Historically, the Japanese were almost vegetarian.  From the 10th to the 19th century, the majority of the Japanese population lived on a diet of very little meat.


Historically alone is vague, in your example you added specific dates.

@Mari-LouA.  vague is not (grammatically) wrong. The original question seems to be asking whether that example sentence is idiomatic and correct English or not. I say that it is.  Do you disagree?

EDITED Used alone "historically" is vague. The OP in their examples did not mention any dates while you did. Adding dates makes a huge difference, it gives the reader invaluable information and helps clarify what period the writer is referring to. “Historically, American prisoners were given lobster to eat.“ Which period am I referring to? Which centuries? Both the OP's sentence are grammatical, no one is contesting that.

"no one is contesting that".  Well, the other answers seem to be contesting that. And since this the English learners stackexchange, I would assume that the primary purpose is to help distinguish what is correct and idiomatic.  It should be OBVIOUS to any person who knows at least basic English, regardless of their native langauge, that "historically" by itself does not indicate a specific time period.


Can I use "historically" to mean "for a long time" in "Historically, the Japanese were almost vegetarian"?

"Historically" is not a clean fit for this usage.  It does not mean "for a long time".  That may sometimes be an implication following from the larger context, but if you specifically mean "for a long time" then you should say that clearly.
However, I don't think you actually do mean "for a long time".  I take the sentence to be trying to say something a bit more specific, perhaps better phrased along these lines:

Throughout most of Japanese history, the Japanese diet was primarily plant-based.

